# Why is character A not assigned to environment variable using set %Variable%=A in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have a batch file that detects if the user presses key <kbd>A</kbd> and if so should change the `char` variable to `A` instead of `.` But for some unknown reason that does not work. I don't know why.

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
set char=.
:start
cls
batbox.exe /k
if %errorlevel%==97 set %char%=A && goto next
goto start
:next
echo %char%
pause
```

If you need the batbox command info, here is the [link.](http://dos9.org/doc/en/html/batbox.html)

Comment: Please provide a **specific question title** like recommended here: [ask]! Furthermore, describe what the script is supposed to do and what it actually does; *"it won't work"* is definitely not a sufficient error description!

Comment: So you are just using batbox to get user input?  Why wouldn't you just use the `SET /P` or `CHOICE` commands?

Comment: Thanks for you help everyone. I will try to keep these tips in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your trying to do something like this:

```
@Echo off
Set Char=.

:Start
Cls
Choice /C an /T 10 /D n /N /M "Press a or wait"
Echo %Char%
Pause
Goto :start
```

You only have to throw in some of your own code to make it work like you want.
Quick run down from here /C is choices /T is time /D is what answer it does when the time runs out /N is for not showing the available answers and /M is message for the user.

Source: [Batch Choice Information](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php)

Comment: After `choice` you should insert `if %ErrorLevel% EQU 1 set "Char=A"`, and you should remove the `pause` command, to achieve the same as the OP attempted in his question...